# Ordered union of Borel sets

Tags: set-theory, measure-theory

Let $\mathfrak{A}$ be an uncountable collection of Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^d$ such that for any $A,B\in\mathfrak{A}$, either $A\subset B$ or $A\supset B$. Then is it necessarily true that the union $\bigcup_{A\in\mathfrak{A}}A$ is Borel measurable?

Comment: Every set of size $\aleph_1$ can be written in this way, so "no".

Comment: Thank you for the response! Is it possible to provide a reference or proof for your answer?

Comment: Since the set has size $\aleph_1$, you can write it as a union of a linearly ordered collection of countable sets. All countable sets are automatically Borel.

Comment: I am still confused... Say, we have a set $[0,1]$. How do we write it as the union of ordered set $\{A_i:i\in I\}$, in which each $A_i$ is countable? Can you give me an example of these $A_i$?

Comment: @31415926 For $[0,1]$ that would be equivalent to assuming the continuum hypothesis.

Comment: To complete the answer given by @FrançoisG.Dorais in a comment, note that there is (assuming ZFC) a non-Borel set of size $\aleph_1$. Take a set $X$ of reals of size $\aleph_1$: If the continuum hypothesis holds, then $X$ has more than continuum many subsets of size $\aleph_1$ but there are only continuum many Borel sets. If the continuum hypothesis fails, then $X$ itself isn't Borel because all uncountable Borel sets have the cardinality of the continuum.

Comment: @AndreasBlass: Indeed, if the continuum hypothesis holds, you may simply take the Vitali set or your other favorite non-Borel set; it will automatically have cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: An algebraic synthesis of some already given answers: it is a simple fact that a Boolean subalgebra of a given complete Boolean algebra stable under taking arbitrary supremums, if and only if it is stable under taking supremums of (well-ordered) chains. Hence, in a $T_0$ topological space ($T_0$ means that singletons are Borel), the Borel Boolean subalgebra has the property of being stable under taking unions of chains iff it is the whole power set.

Comment: @AndreasBlass maybe I am missing something obvious, but if CH fails, why all uncountable Borel sets have the cardinality of continuum? It seems to me the opposite: if CH holds then the cardinality of any uncountable Borel set is at most $2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$ and at least $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @Skeeve Whether or not CH holds, every uncountable Borel set (in a separable metric space) includes a homeomorphic copy of the Cantor set and therefore has the cardinality of the continuum. (See for example Theorem 13.6 in Kechris's book "Classical Descriptive Set Theory" or Corollary 2C.3 of Moschovakis's book "Descriptive Set Theory".) This holds whether or not CH holds, but it's useful in my earlier comment just when CH fails.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Construction

Consider some non-Borel set $Y \subset [0,1]$ (e.g. Vitali set).

Enumerate $Y$ using ordinals as $Y=\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha < \beta}$.
Let $m$ denote the smallest ordinal such that $X=\{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha < m}$ is non-Borel. Note that $m\ge \omega_1$, since otherwise $X$ would be at most countable.

Then the family $\mathfrak A = \{A_\gamma\}_{\gamma<m}$, where $A_\gamma = \{x_\alpha\}_{\alpha<\gamma}$, has the properties desired in the OP, but $\bigcup_{A \in \mathfrak A} A$ is non-Borel.

For more details about ordinals see e.g. *Set theory* by T. Jech (2006).

#### Discussion of cardinality

Let us prove that in fact $|X| = \aleph_1$.

Indeed, by construction $\aleph_1 \le |X| \le 2^{\aleph_0}$.
Any uncountable Borel set has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$ (e.g. by Theorem 13.6 in *Classical Descriptive Set Theory* by A.S. Kechris or Corollary 2C.3 in *Descriptive Set Theory* by Y.M. Moschovakis.). Therefore, if CH fails then $|X|\le \aleph_1$, since otherwise there would exist a Borel subset with cardinality $\aleph_1$ (by minimality of $m$). On the other hand if CH holds then immediately $|X| = \aleph_1$.

*Most of this answer comes from the very useful comments in this thread.*

Comment: You seem to use the inequality $2^{\aleph_0}<2^{\aleph_1}$, also known as "weak CH".  This is not provable in ZFC.  - Also, I don't think you can prove from ZF (without AC)  that the reals contain a set  of cardinality $\aleph_1$.

Comment: Also, without choice, it is consistent that every set of reals is Borel.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out, I was not aware of these facts! (corrected the answer)

Comment: You haven't. You still appear to claim that $2^{\aleph _0}<2^{\aleph_1}$.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. It is not clear wether one avoid using weak CH (I will try to come back to this later).

Comment: Why don't you just take a non-Borel set of minimum cardinality and well-order it so all initial segments have lower cardinality? That just needs AC, no CH at all.

Comment: The comment of Andreas Blass on the question gives another argument that, in ZFC, there exists a non-Borel set of cardinality $\aleph_1$.  Again, no CH needed.

Comment: @bof thanks a lot for the suggestion, I've updated my answer using it.

Comment: @NateEldredge thanks a lot, I've tried to integrate that approach into my answer.

Comment: Got it. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Every coanalytic set can be written as a union of $\aleph_1$-many Borel sets. (For example, see Theorem 4.3.17 of [Srivastava](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387984124).) Take a coanalytic non-Borel set $B \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$. Then $B = \bigcup_{\alpha < \omega_1} B_{\alpha}$ for some Borel sets $B_{\alpha}$. For each $\alpha < \omega_1$, set $C_{\alpha} = \bigcup_{\delta < \alpha} B_{\delta}$. Clearly each $C_{\alpha}$ is Borel since it is a countable union of Borel sets. On the other hand, $\bigcup_{\alpha < \omega_1} C_{\alpha}=\bigcup_{\alpha < \omega_1} B_{\alpha}=B$ is non-Borel.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the answer!